# Storm Crawler to fetch urls with query string

Tags: stormcrawler

I am new to storm crawler. I could configure storm crawler to fetch and parse the url "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18926286/". But, my need is to crawl https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18926286/?format=pubmed
But, when I give this url (tried both Memory Spout and URL Frontier), the output is same as for https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18926286/.
Is there any specific setting to be done for accepting query strings?

I was expecting the same output when I put https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18926286/?format=pubmed in browser

The urlfilters.json -> I do not think I made any changes from defaults. This  is the content.

```
{
    "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.URLFilters": [
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLFilter",
            "name": "BasicURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxPathRepetition": 3,
                "maxLength": 1024
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.depth.MaxDepthFilter",
            "name": "MaxDepthFilter",
            "params": {
                "maxDepth": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.BasicURLNormalizer",
            "name": "BasicURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "removeAnchorPart": true,
                "unmangleQueryString": true,
                "checkValidURI": true,
                "removeHashes": true,
                "hostIDNtoASCII": true
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.host.HostURLFilter",
            "name": "HostURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "ignoreOutsideHost": true,
                "ignoreOutsideDomain": true
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLNormalizer",
            "name": "RegexURLNormalizer",
            "params": {
                "regexNormalizerFile": "default-regex-normalizers.xml"
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.regex.RegexURLFilter",
            "name": "RegexURLFilter",
            "params": {
                "regexFilterFile": "default-regex-filters.txt"
            }
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.basic.SelfURLFilter",
            "name": "SelfURLFilter"
        },
        {
            "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.filtering.sitemap.SitemapFilter",
            "name": "SitemapFilter"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Probably the URLFiltering. Would you mind sharing the content of urlfilters.json in src/main/resources? Which version of SC are you on?

Comment: SC version is 2.4.0. Thank you for the response.

Comment: The urlfilters.json -> I have added to the main question.

Comment: In default-regex-normalizers.xml, I see below. Since, it is commented, I believe, query string should be fine. Is there any possibility that at the website side, when crawl is detected, they do something? When I use curl or postman or browser, I get the response correctly. 
<!-- Removes query strings -->
<!--<regex>-->
    <!--<pattern>\?.*$</pattern>-->
    <!--<substitution></substitution>-->
<!--</regex>-->

Comment: And I believe you asked for Crawler version and not storm version. Below is my pom.xml
 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <stormcrawler.version>2.8</stormcrawler.version>
  <storm.version>2.4.0</storm.version>
 </properties>

Answer (score 0):

I have just [merged a PR](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/1079), see https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/pull/1081.

This should help you test the filtering steps on the URL passed as input. It should be possible to pass a source URL as a 2nd argument.

Maybe try pulling the main branch, recompiling SC and make your topo code depend on the snapshot version.

You can test the metadata from the fetching with

storm local target/xxxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.protocol.okhttp.HttpProtocol https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18926286/?format=pubmed

Just to check, what do you use for indexing the content? Is the URL looking incorrect there or in the status (i.e URLFrontier)?